# IndexOf and multi array

Tags: javascript, indexof

I've this problem with this code. This code should return "Interior decoration learning" but it keeps returning "home decoration learning", What am I doing wrong?

```
var forbidden = "home decor learn";
var items = [
  ["decor", "decoration"],  
  ["learn", "learning"],
  ["home", "interior"],
];

for(i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
    if(forbidden.indexOf(items[i][0])){
        forbidden = forbidden.replace(items[i][0], items[i][1]);
    }
}
document.write(forbidden);
```

Thank you,

Comment: If nothing is found `indexOf`is `-1`, not `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forbidden.indexOf(items[i][0])` returns the position of the match or `-1` if there is no match. That means it is truthy when there is no match or when there is a match anywhere other that the start of the string. The only time it returns a falsy value is when it matches the very start of the string and returns `0`, as is the case with `"home"` in your scenario.

To use `indexOf` as a test to see if a string contains a value you need your test to check whether it returned `-1` or any other number (EG. you can use conditions like `!== -1` or `>= 0`). In modern JavaScript engines or with a very simple SHIM you can use [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead which returns a boolean and better signifies your intention.

In your case you don't really need an `if` statement at all. Just do the replacement and rely on the fact that [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is a  no-op if it can't find the replacement pattern:

```js
var forbidden = "home decor learn";
var items = [
  ["decor", "decoration"],  
  ["learn", "learning"],
  ["home", "interior"],
];

for(i = 0; i<items.length; i++){
    forbidden = forbidden.replace(items[i][0], items[i][1]);
}
document.write(forbidden);
```

Note: [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the ***first*** match when used with string or a non-global regex as the replacement pattern. That means your code will allow forbidden words, so long as the occur at least twice. A workaround for that is beyond the scope of this answer.